# Does the matrix of all arrangements of standard basis vectors have a name?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For example, in $\mathbb{R}^2$, we have the standard basis

$$ \beta = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} \right\} $$

What I mean by all arrangements of the standard basis vectors is that the first column of the matrix contains one copy of each basis vector. Successive columns have the same vectors but in a different order. The details are more easily shown by example:

$$A_2=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

So, $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ is in the top left and the bottom right. We can represent these matrices as images with black representing zeros and white representing ones. Here is one for $\mathbb{R}^3$:

[image: 9 row, 6 column matrix populated by copies of three basis vectors]

And here is one for $\mathbb{R}^4$:

[image: 16 row, 24 column matrix populated by copies of four basis vectors]

Some properties of them are that every column has $n$ ones (by definition), while every row has $(n-1)!$ ones. The rank is equal to $n^2-2n+2$. The most interesting property I found was that the product $A_nA_n^T$ has a curious simplicity, being writable in terms of the Kroneker product $\otimes$, the identity $I_n$, and the all-ones matrix $J_n$ as:

$$A_nA_n^T=(n-1)!I_n\otimes I_n + (n-2)!(J_n-I_n) \otimes(J_n - I_n)$$

Or, as an image for $n=6$ where white is $(n-1)!$ and grey is $(n-2)!$:

[image: 36 by 36 matrix described by the preceding equation]

Which is why the rank is what it is. I have determined why this pattern happens, but I don't think it's relevant to this question.

Is there a name for these matrices? Or alternatively, is there an equivalent formulation with a name?

Comment: It should be possible to write the $A$ matrices in terms of the vectorization of a basis matrix (whose columns are the basis vectors) and permutation matrices (built from smaller permutation matrices using the Kronecker product).